# visual studio 2008 express takes long time to run c++ application in debug mode (small one)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, performance

i don't know why but i have a project that i moving its source code ( not project files ) 
from computer to computer via dropbox . now in few computers when i hit f5 in debug mode
it take the visual studio like 5 minutes until its loads its dll's it needs to run  (im using Qt application ) . i must say that the pc is using the configuration on all pc's .
what can cause this slowness in loading and running the application from within visual studio.?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {

     QApplication app(argc, argv);
     QCoreApplication::setApplicationName(APP_NAME);
     QCoreApplication::setApplicationVersion(APP_VERISON);
     QCoreApplication::setOrganizationDomain(APP_DOMAIN);
     app.setStyle("WindowsXP");    
     QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("utf8"));
     QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));



     WRITELOG(pi::getInstance()->GetUserAccessToken());
     mainWindowContainer.show();


     return app.exec();
 }
```

here is the Modules windows output if its helps

```
foo.exe G:\c++\qt\qt4.7\foo\debug\foo.exe   N/A N/A Symbols loaded. G:\c++\qt\qt4.7\foo\debug\foo.pdb   1       5/31/2011 9:47 PM   00400000-00514000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
ntdll.dll   C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll   N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     2   5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   7C900000-7C9B0000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
kernel32.dll    C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll    N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     3   5.1.2600.3119 (xpsp_sp2_gdr.070416-1301)    4/16/2007 6:52 PM   7C800000-7C8F5000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
QtWebKitd4.dll  G:\Qt\4.7.3\bin\QtWebKitd4.dll  N/A N/A Symbols loaded. G:\Qt\4.7.3\bin\QtWebKitd4.pdb  4   4.07.3.0    3/30/2011 11:29 AM  10000000-114CD000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
winmm.dll   C:\WINDOWS\system32\winmm.dll   N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     5   5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:57 AM   76B40000-76B6D000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
user32.dll  C:\WINDOWS\system32\user32.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     6   5.1.2600.3099 (xpsp_sp2_gdr.070308-0222)    3/8/2007 6:36 PM    7E410000-7E4A0000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
gdi32.dll   C:\WINDOWS\system32\gdi32.dll   N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     7   5.1.2600.3466 (xpsp_sp2_gdr.081022-1254)    10/23/2008 4:01 PM  77F10000-77F58000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
advapi32.dll    C:\WINDOWS\system32\advapi32.dll    N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     8   5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   77DD0000-77E6B000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
rpcrt4.dll  C:\WINDOWS\system32\rpcrt4.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     9   5.1.2600.3173 (xpsp_sp2_gdr.070709-0051)    7/9/2007 4:09 PM    77E70000-77F02000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
secur32.dll C:\WINDOWS\system32\secur32.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     10  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   77FE0000-77FF1000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
shlwapi.dll C:\WINDOWS\system32\shlwapi.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     11  6.00.2900.3462 (xpsp_sp2_gdr.081015-1244)   10/16/2008 1:37 PM  77F60000-77FD6000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
msvcrt.dll  C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     12  7.0.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:59 AM   77C10000-77C68000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
version.dll C:\WINDOWS\system32\version.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     13  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   77C00000-77C08000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
phonond4.dll    G:\Qt\4.7.3\bin\phonond4.dll    N/A N/A Symbols loaded. G:\Qt\4.7.3\bin\phonond4.pdb    14  4.04.0.0    3/30/2011 9:30 AM   00350000-003D1000*  [4472] foo.exe: Native  
QtGuid4.dll G:\Qt\4.7.3\bin\QtGuid4.dll N/A N/A Symbols loaded. G:\Qt\4.7.3\bin\QtGuid4.pdb 15  4.07.3.0    3/30/2011 9:07 AM   65000000-65DC2000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
comdlg32.dll    C:\WINDOWS\system32\comdlg32.dll    N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     16  6.00.2900.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)   8/4/2004 10:56 AM   763B0000-763F9000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
comctl32.dll    C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.2982_x-ww_ac3f9c03\comctl32.dll   N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     17  6.0 (xpsp.060825-0040)  8/25/2006 6:45 PM   773D0000-774D3000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
shell32.dll C:\WINDOWS\system32\shell32.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     18  6.00.2900.3402 (xpsp_sp2_gdr.080702-1233)   7/3/2008 4:16 PM    7C9C0000-7D1D6000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
oleaut32.dll    C:\WINDOWS\system32\oleaut32.dll    N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     19  5.01.2600.3266  12/4/2007 9:38 PM   77120000-771AB000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
ole32.dll   C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll   N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     20  5.1.2600.2726 (xpsp_sp2_gdr.050725-1528)    7/26/2005 7:39 AM   774E0000-7761D000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
imm32.dll   C:\WINDOWS\system32\imm32.dll   N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     21  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   76390000-763AD000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
winspool.drv    C:\WINDOWS\system32\winspool.drv    N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     22  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   73000000-73026000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
QtCored4.dll    G:\Qt\4.7.3\bin\QtCored4.dll    N/A N/A Symbols loaded. G:\Qt\4.7.3\bin\QtCored4.pdb    23  4.07.3.0    3/30/2011 8:55 AM   67000000-673F4000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
ws2_32.dll  C:\WINDOWS\system32\ws2_32.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     24  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:57 AM   71AB0000-71AC7000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
ws2help.dll C:\WINDOWS\system32\ws2help.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     25  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:57 AM   71AA0000-71AA8000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
msvcp90d.dll    C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_x-ww_f863c71f\msvcp90d.dll   N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     26  9.00.30729.1    7/29/2008 1:54 PM   00530000-00607000*  [4472] foo.exe: Native  
msvcr90d.dll    C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_x-ww_f863c71f\msvcr90d.dll   N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     27  9.00.30729.1    7/29/2008 1:53 PM   00610000-00733000*  [4472] foo.exe: Native  
QtNetworkd4.dll G:\Qt\4.7.3\bin\QtNetworkd4.dll N/A N/A Symbols loaded. G:\Qt\4.7.3\bin\QtNetworkd4.pdb 28  4.07.3.0    3/30/2011 8:58 AM   64000000-64198000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
QtXmld4.dll G:\Qt\4.7.3\bin\QtXmld4.dll N/A N/A Symbols loaded. G:\Qt\4.7.3\bin\QtXmld4.pdb 29  4.07.3.0    3/30/2011 8:57 AM   61000000-61096000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
lpk.dll C:\WINDOWS\system32\lpk.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     30  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   629C0000-629C9000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
usp10.dll   C:\WINDOWS\system32\usp10.dll   N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     31  1.0420.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158) 8/4/2004 10:56 AM   74D90000-74DFB000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
msctf.dll   C:\WINDOWS\system32\msctf.dll   N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     32  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:57 AM   74720000-7476B000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
msctfime.ime    C:\WINDOWS\system32\msctfime.ime    N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     33  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:57 AM   755C0000-755EE000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
uxtheme.dll C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     34  6.00.2900.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)   8/4/2004 10:56 AM   5AD70000-5ADA8000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
qgenericbearerd4.dll    G:\Qt\4.7.3\plugins\bearer\qgenericbearerd4.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     35  4.07.3.0    3/30/2011 12:46 PM  00FB0000-00FCC000*  [4472] foo.exe: Native  
iphlpapi.dll    C:\WINDOWS\system32\iphlpapi.dll    N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     36  5.1.2600.2912 (xpsp_sp2_gdr.060519-0003)    5/19/2006 3:59 PM   76D60000-76D79000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
netman.dll  C:\WINDOWS\system32\netman.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     37  5.1.2600.2743 (xpsp_sp2_gdr.050819-1525)    8/22/2005 9:29 PM   77D00000-77D33000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
mprapi.dll  C:\WINDOWS\system32\mprapi.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     38  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   76D40000-76D58000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
activeds.dll    C:\WINDOWS\system32\activeds.dll    N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     39  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   77CC0000-77CF2000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
adsldpc.dll C:\WINDOWS\system32\adsldpc.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     40  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   76E10000-76E35000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
netapi32.dll    C:\WINDOWS\system32\netapi32.dll    N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     41  5.1.2600.3462 (xpsp_sp2_gdr.081015-1244)    10/15/2008 7:57 PM  5B860000-5B8B4000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
wldap32.dll C:\WINDOWS\system32\wldap32.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     42  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   76F60000-76F8C000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
atl.dll C:\WINDOWS\system32\atl.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     43  3.05.2284.0 8/4/2004 10:56 AM   76B20000-76B31000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
rtutils.dll C:\WINDOWS\system32\rtutils.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     44  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   76E80000-76E8E000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
samlib.dll  C:\WINDOWS\system32\samlib.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     45  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   71BF0000-71C03000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
setupapi.dll    C:\WINDOWS\system32\setupapi.dll    N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     46  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   77920000-77A13000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
netshell.dll    C:\WINDOWS\system32\netshell.dll    N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     47  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   76400000-765A6000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
credui.dll  C:\WINDOWS\system32\credui.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     48  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   76C00000-76C2E000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
rasapi32.dll    C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasapi32.dll    N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     49  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   76EE0000-76F1C000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
rasman.dll  C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasman.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     50  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   76E90000-76EA2000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
tapi32.dll  C:\WINDOWS\system32\tapi32.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     51  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   76EB0000-76EDF000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
wininet.dll C:\WINDOWS\system32\wininet.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     52  8.00.6001.18702 (longhorn_ie8_rtm(wmbla).090308-0339)   3/8/2009 2:34 PM    63000000-630E6000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
normaliz.dll    C:\WINDOWS\system32\normaliz.dll    N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     53  6.0.5441.0 (winmain(wmbla).060628-1735) 6/29/2006 6:05 PM   00FF0000-00FF9000*  [4472] foo.exe: Native  
urlmon.dll  C:\WINDOWS\system32\urlmon.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     54  8.00.6001.18702 (longhorn_ie8_rtm(wmbla).090308-0339)   3/8/2009 2:34 PM    1A400000-1A532000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
iertutil.dll    C:\WINDOWS\system32\iertutil.dll    N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     55  8.00.6001.18702 (longhorn_ie8_rtm(wmbla).090308-0339)   3/8/2009 2:32 PM    5DCA0000-5DE88000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
wzcsapi.dll C:\WINDOWS\system32\wzcsapi.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     56  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:57 AM   73030000-73040000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
wzcsvc.dll  C:\WINDOWS\system32\wzcsvc.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     57  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:57 AM   77620000-7768E000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
wmi.dll C:\WINDOWS\system32\wmi.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     58  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   76D30000-76D34000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
dhcpcsvc.dll    C:\WINDOWS\system32\dhcpcsvc.dll    N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     59  5.1.2600.2912 (xpsp_sp2_gdr.060519-0003)    5/19/2006 3:59 PM   76D80000-76D9E000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
dnsapi.dll  C:\WINDOWS\system32\dnsapi.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     60  5.1.2600.3394 (xpsp_sp2_gdr.080620-1245)    6/20/2008 8:41 PM   76F20000-76F47000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
crypt32.dll C:\WINDOWS\system32\crypt32.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     61  5.131.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)  8/4/2004 10:56 AM   77A80000-77B14000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
msasn1.dll  C:\WINDOWS\system32\msasn1.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     62  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:57 AM   77B20000-77B32000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
wtsapi32.dll    C:\WINDOWS\system32\wtsapi32.dll    N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     63  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:57 AM   76F50000-76F58000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
winsta.dll  C:\WINDOWS\system32\winsta.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     64  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   76360000-76370000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
esent.dll   C:\WINDOWS\system32\esent.dll   N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     65  5.1.2600.2780 (xpsp_sp2_gdr.051019-1518)    10/21/2005 1:20 AM  606B0000-607BD000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
userenv.dll C:\WINDOWS\system32\userenv.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     66  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   769C0000-76A73000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
msv1_0.dll  C:\WINDOWS\system32\msv1_0.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     67  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:59 AM   77C70000-77C93000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
clbcatq.dll C:\WINDOWS\system32\clbcatq.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     68  2001.12.4414.308    7/26/2005 7:39 AM   76FD0000-7704F000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
comres.dll  C:\WINDOWS\system32\comres.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     69  2001.12.4414.258    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   77050000-77115000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
xpsp2res.dll    C:\WINDOWS\system32\xpsp2res.dll    N/A N/A Binary was not built with debug information.        70  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   20000000-202C5000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
qnativewifibearerd4.dll G:\Qt\4.7.3\plugins\bearer\qnativewifibearerd4.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     71  4.07.3.0    3/30/2011 12:47 PM  01960000-0197E000*  [4472] foo.exe: Native  
qcncodecsd4.dll G:\Qt\4.7.3\plugins\codecs\qcncodecsd4.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     72  4.07.3.0    3/30/2011 12:47 PM  01990000-019C5000*  [4472] foo.exe: Native  
qjpcodecsd4.dll G:\Qt\4.7.3\plugins\codecs\qjpcodecsd4.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     73  4.07.3.0    3/30/2011 12:47 PM  019E0000-01A1E000*  [4472] foo.exe: Native  
qkrcodecsd4.dll G:\Qt\4.7.3\plugins\codecs\qkrcodecsd4.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     74  4.07.3.0    3/30/2011 12:47 PM  01A30000-01A52000*  [4472] foo.exe: Native  
qtwcodecsd4.dll G:\Qt\4.7.3\plugins\codecs\qtwcodecsd4.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     75  4.07.3.0    3/30/2011 12:47 PM  01A70000-01AA9000*  [4472] foo.exe: Native  
qgifd4.dll  G:\Qt\4.7.3\plugins\imageformats\qgifd4.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     76  4.07.3.0    3/30/2011 12:48 PM  01F90000-01FA4000*  [4472] foo.exe: Native  
qicod4.dll  G:\Qt\4.7.3\plugins\imageformats\qicod4.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     77  4.07.3.0    3/30/2011 12:49 PM  01FC0000-01FD4000*  [4472] foo.exe: Native  
qjpegd4.dll G:\Qt\4.7.3\plugins\imageformats\qjpegd4.dll    N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     78  4.07.3.0    3/30/2011 12:48 PM  01FF0000-0204E000*  [4472] foo.exe: Native  
qmngd4.dll  G:\Qt\4.7.3\plugins\imageformats\qmngd4.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     79  4.07.3.0    3/30/2011 12:48 PM  02060000-020D7000*  [4472] foo.exe: Native  
qsvgd4.dll  G:\Qt\4.7.3\plugins\imageformats\qsvgd4.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     80  4.07.3.0    3/30/2011 12:48 PM  020F0000-02100000*  [4472] foo.exe: Native  
QtSvgd4.dll G:\Qt\4.7.3\bin\QtSvgd4.dll N/A N/A Symbols loaded. G:\Qt\4.7.3\bin\QtSvgd4.pdb 81  4.07.3.0    3/30/2011 9:33 AM   66000000-66083000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
qtiffd4.dll G:\Qt\4.7.3\plugins\imageformats\qtiffd4.dll    N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     82  4.07.3.0    3/30/2011 12:48 PM  02120000-0219C000*  [4472] foo.exe: Native  
ssleay32.dll    C:\WINDOWS\system32\ssleay32.dll    N/A N/A Binary was not built with debug information.        83  0.09.8.7    5/3/2008 12:31 AM   021B0000-021E2000*  [4472] foo.exe: Native  
libeay32.dll    C:\WINDOWS\system32\libeay32.dll    N/A N/A Binary was not built with debug information.        84  0.09.8.7    5/3/2008 12:31 AM   021F0000-022FF000*  [4472] foo.exe: Native  
wsock32.dll C:\WINDOWS\system32\wsock32.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     85  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:57 AM   71AD0000-71AD9000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
rsaenh.dll  C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll  N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     86  5.1.2600.2161 (xpsp.040706-1629)    7/7/2004 5:17 AM    0FFD0000-0FFF8000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
mswsock.dll C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     87  5.1.2600.3394 (xpsp_sp2_gdr.080620-1245)    6/20/2008 8:41 PM   71A50000-71A8F000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
mdnsNSP.dll C:\Program Files\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll    N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     88  1.00.6.2    11/11/2008 2:48 AM  16080000-160A5000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
rasadhlp.dll    C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasadhlp.dll    N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     89  5.1.2600.2938 (xpsp_sp2_gdr.060626-0020)    6/26/2006 8:37 PM   76FC0000-76FC6000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
hnetcfg.dll C:\WINDOWS\system32\hnetcfg.dll N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     90  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:56 AM   662B0000-66308000   [4472] foo.exe: Native  
wshtcpip.dll    C:\WINDOWS\system32\wshtcpip.dll    N/A N/A Symbols not loaded.     91  5.1.2600.2180 (xpsp_sp2_rtm.040803-2158)    8/4/2004 10:57 AM   71A90000-71A98000   [4472] foo.exe: Native
```

**Update**
Does any one knows how to turn on the visual studio express 2008 logs on ?
there is no devenv.exe on express , but how do i turn the IDE logs on?

Comment: Try disabling the symbol lookup for qt, that should decrease the debug start-up time.

Comment: The rules got changed? Wait- there are posting rules?

Comment: @DeadMG - The heuristics for automatic question filtering have been improved lately. Starting out with "i don't know why but i have a project" might trigger that.

Comment: Bo Persson: improved ? ok ....

Comment: @Blindy how do i do that disable the lookup?

Comment: Well from what you pasted they're already not loaded, except your own executable, so no luck there. Was worth a shot I guess, but this is why I didn't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The IDE is probably trying to load symbol files from the Internet or some inaccessible location.  This does not happen when you run from the command line.

Check out the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x54fht41.aspx) on how to properly configure symbol file usage in Visual Studio.  VS2008 data is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x54fht41%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Note that you should be able to track progress of the process startup in the IDE's output windows (Command/Debug).  This may show you some supporting information for my hypothesis, or some other pointer to the true solution.

Comment: the IDE output windows is just in freeze until i see that its starting to load the dll's

Comment: Have you tried symbol reconfiguration as suggested here (or disabled it, as in the comments)?  Did that help?

Comment: how can i see what is holding the IDE in freeze? is there somekind of VC log?

Comment: Steve Townsend :yes i did it , still freeze